# Type a interlinear text, bi or tri-lingual

Tags: macros, linguistics

I need to do an interlinear text. If I understood the problem correctly, I need a macro or format that will treat each word as a three-story fraction. Top store, a number reference, mid store one language,low store another language.  But those fractions , as words, must have in the middle store, to be connected,separated with, commas,, colons, etc. And the line is to be justified, so the size of word will influence the size of the line, a decision is to be made on how to justify.   do not know if I have been clear.There will be cross references to footnotes, also. Well, page section and cross references do not appear to be very difficult. What seems critical is that "semi-mathematical" treatment of the three-story words... I imagine context or xetex/xelatex to be adequate, but...I expect proper advice

Comment: I don't quite understand. I think I would have to see a picture.

Comment: Possibly like [this one?](http://wiki.logos.com/media/Interlinear4b.png)

Answer (score 11):

Depending on your actual needs, this looks very much like the kind of job for the [`expex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/expex) package.

The ExPex package provides very sophisticated glossing macros which should do what you need.  Here's an example from the documentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expex}
\begin{document}

\ex[glhangstyle=none]
\let\\=\textsc
\begingl
\gla
Hom\^{a}o sa \v{c}\^{o} p\^{o} tha  \~{n}u nao ng\u{a} hmua. \~{N}u
dj\u{a} g\u{a}, \~{n}u dj\u{a} \v{c}\u{o}ng \~{n}u, laih gui r\^{e}o
\~{n}u. Todang bboi r\^{o}k jolan \~{n}u nao hma, \~{n}u bb\^{o}h sa
droi mr\u{a} d\u{o} bboi gah, a, hruh \~{n}u.//
\glb
\\{exist} one \\{clf} person old \\{3s} go do field \\{3s} hold
machete \\{3s} hold hoe \\{3s} and carry.on.back back.basket \\{3s}
while at along trail \\{3s} go field \\{3s} see one \\{clf} peacock
stay at \\{drct} -- nest \\{3s}//
\glft
`There was an old person who went to work in the field. He took
along his machete, he took along his hoe, and he carried his
basket on his back. While he was on his way to the farm, he saw a
peacock beside its nest.'//
\endgl
\xe

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of code]

Comment: Thank you, Alan. Please, let me bother you a little more asking you to peep into www.bibliaapostolica.com and www.apostolicbible.com. The top line of each word is a code number or an asterisk, if it is a proper name. Then Greek, and then the target language.

Comment: Is there a way to not italicize the first row?

Comment: How do I remove the indexing? Or substitute it with a string label, like `Example 1`?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this a linguistic question? Jürgen Fenn maintains a topic catalogue of packages on CTAN. It is always usefull to start there. For linguistic packages see here: http://texcatalogue.sarovar.org/bytopic.html#linguistics

However, I remember discussions here in Germany. In 2008, somebody published on PSTricks for linguistic texts in our TeX-Journal. I faintly remember it was no easy going. So may be you can give us more details and we come back with better advice.

Comment: This list is somewhat out of date. The [tag:linguistics] tag also gives a list, including some more recent packages.

Comment: @AlanMunn The expex package will never make it into the topic index of CTAN as long as it is not on CTAN. I wonder why somebody undertakes to write such a difficult piece of software without pushing it into _THE_ repository.

Comment: John *does* put stuff up on CTAN (`pst-jtree` and `pst-asr` are there) but he's quite conservative about putting packages that are still in his opinion in beta (although lots of people are using it.)  My comment more referred to the fact that neither `tikz-qtree` nor `ot-tableau` are listed (which are on CTAN).

Comment: @AlanMunn Easy to answer: you have to be a linguist to comprehend that tikz-qtree is a linguistic package. And regarding ot-tableau the announcment said: »The ot-tableau package makes it easy to create beautiful
optimality-theoretic tableaux.« In German: Hääää?

Comment: Thanks to everyone!  I am not as yet able to provide adequate feedback. But I can see I have much to study to be able to even appropriately appreciate (let alone, evaluate) your contributions, as i was doing everything "mechanically". Now I know I MUST "learn Chemistry even to strain coffee", as I was once criticized! Thanks VERY, VERY MUCH!! Learning, and learning still more is always the only choice left!!! Eventually I will return, after further study and experimentation!