# How to format an arbitrary number of lines in interlinear text

Tags: linguistics, gb4e, expex, covington

I'm searching for packages for formatting interlinear text with an arbitrary number of lines.  So far, it seems that the packages `gb4e`, `covington`, `expex` only format up to three aligned lines. (`covington` and `gb4e` provide `\gll`, and `\glll` but no `\gllll`, for example).

I've found references to SIL's ITF software (http://www.sil.org/computing/catalog/show_software.asp?id=17) which supposedly accomplishes this, but no real instructions on usage.

This task can obviously be accomplished using the tabular environment, but I'm trying to figure out if there are any established packages which provide an environment that carries out most of the dirty work.

Comment: Have you seen http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45520/doing-an-interlinear-text?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Expex can handle an unlimited number of gloss lines. It's not obvious from the documentation, but you can have as many `\glb` rows as you want:

```
\gla vernacular text //
\glb first gloss //
\glb second gloss //
\glb etc. //
```

The letters basically denote different styles, so as long as you don't need the aligned tiers formatted in more than three different styles (`\gla, \glb, \glc`), this should be all you need.

Answer (score 3):

In version 5.0 of the `expex` package, so called `nlevel` syntax has been introduced, which allows for an arbitrary number of glosses with arbitrary styles. The following simple example features the acutal sentence in italics, positional morphological tags in a fixed width font, syntactic functions in a proportional font, semantic functors in small caps, and a gloss in whatever style is set for running text.

```
    \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{expexlocal}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \begin{document}
    \pex[glstyle=nlevel,glneveryline={\it,\small\ttfamily,\small\rmfamily,\small\sc}]
    \begingl
      Informační[AANS1----1A----/Atr/rstr/information{\tiny\sc ADJ}]
      středisko[NNNS1-----A----/Sb/act/office]
      podpoří[VB-S---3P-AA---/Pred/pred/will support]
      export.[NNIS4-----A----/Obj/pat/export]
      \glft `An information office will support export.'
    \endgl
    \xe
    \end{document}
```

[image]