# How to get a first unglossed line with linguex

Tags: linguex

I'm stumped with how I might use linguex to get an unglossed first line, then give a second line with morpheme breakdowns, the morpheme-by-morpheme gloss on the third line, and the free translation on the fourth line. This would be helpful for languages in which the morphophonology obscures the morphemes themselves. Anyone already done this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! An example, even approximate with a drawing, would be useful for better understanding your intentions.

Comment: Do you want the top line to be aligned word-by-word with lines 2-3? The [IJAL style guide](http://www.americanlinguistics.org/wp-content/uploads/IJAL-interlinear.pdf) recommends 4-line interlinear glossing, but in their examples only lines 2-3 are aligned word-by-word. In other publications I have seen lines 1-3 all aligned word-by-word.

Comment: If you only want lines 2-3 aligned, you should be able to put the top line between the `\ex` and the `\gll` (I don't think you'd be able to use the `\exg` environment, but I will check later), as suggested [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140277/42880) (that answer uses `gb4e` but that uses the same underlying glossing package as `linguex`).

Comment: If you need lines 1-3 to all be aligned, then this is a duplicate of [How to format an arbitrary number of lines in interlinear text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84410/42880) and as far as I know this is only possible with `expex`, as shown in the answers to that question.

Comment: I don't have time right now to write up a full answer showing what you'd have to do for the 2-3 and 1-3 alignment options, but I can do that later. As I said above, it would be helpful to know which option is your desired output (you could edit your answer to include a screenshot of what you'd like). The only package that will let you do both the 2-3 and 1-3 options is `expex`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer depends on what you want to achieve. I can interpret your question in two ways: either the top three lines are all aligned word-by-word (what I'll call the 1-3 option), or only lines 2 and 3 are aligned word-by-word and lines 1 and 4 have normal spacing (what I'll call the 2-3 option). The [IJAL style guide](http://www.americanlinguistics.org/wp-content/uploads/IJAL-interlinear.pdf) recommends 4-line interlinear glossing, and its examples use the 2-3 option, but in many places I have seen the 1-3 option.

### 2-3 Option with `linguex` or `gb4e`

If you want the 2-3 option, you can achieve this in `linguex` if you use the `\gll`/`\glt` syntax for interlinear glossing. You just put the top line between the command that introduces the example and the `\gll`, as shown below. You would do the same if you are using `gb4e`, which uses the same underlying glossing package as `linguex`.

These are the examples from the IJAL style guide. This code needs to be compiled with `xelatex` or `lualatex` because I've used Unicode phonetic symbols and loaded Charis SIL with `fontspec`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}

\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}

\ex. Top line not aligned word-by-word
    \a. katamaːwḛ́ːʍ nakištḭkatká̰n
        \gll ka-tamáː-ʔḛː-w nak=kin-štḭkát-ka̰n \\
            \textsc{opt}-lie.down-\textsc{deb}-\textsc{1pl.sub} \textsc{loc}=1\textsc{po}-sleeping.mat-\textsc{pl.po} \\
        \glt `Let’s lie down on our sleeping mats!'
    \b. a:'jtzananú: chiwíx xli:lh’a:'nankán
        \gll a̰ːxtsananúː čiwíš ḭš-liː-ɬ’a̰ː-nan-kan \\
             long.ago rock \textsc{past}-\textsc{inst}-plow-\textsc{dtrns}-\textsc{idf} \\
        \glt `Long ago they plowed with rocks.'
        
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that you cannot get this extra line if you use the `\exg.`/`\ag.`/`\bg.`/etc. syntax provided by `linguex` because those commands align the first two lines they encounter (they are like `\gll` in that sense).

### 1-3 and 2-3 Options with `expex`

As far as I know, the only package that allows more than 2 aligned lines is [`expex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/expex?lang=en); see [How to format an arbitrary number of lines in interlinear text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84410/42880) for a question specifically about this issue.

For the 1-3 option, you can put the top line in the `\gla` line and then use `\glb` for all subsequent aligned lines. There can only be one `\gla` line but there can be multiple `\glb` lines.

For the 2-3 option, you can put the top line in the `\glpreamble` line and then use `\gla` for the first aligned line and `\glb` for the second aligned line.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}

\usepackage{expex}

\lingset{% my custom formatting for expex glosses
    belowglpreambleskip=-0.2ex,% shrinks the vertical space between the preamble and the top gloss line
    everygla=,% removes the default italic formatting of the top gloss line
    aboveglftskip=-0.2ex,% shrinks the vertical space between the aligned lines and the free translation line
    interpartskip=1ex,% vertical space between parts of examples
    glspace=!0pt plus .2em,% improves line breaking by increasing the maximum horizontal space between aligned words
    glrightskip=0pt plus .5\hsize,% improves line breaking by increasing the maximum horizontal space between end of line and the right margin
    aboveexskip=1ex plus .4ex minus .4ex,% vertical space above examples
    belowexskip=1.5ex plus .4ex minus .4ex% vertical space below examples
}

\begin{document}

\pex 1-3 Option: Top line is aligned word-by-word
\a \begingl
    \gla katamaːwḛ́ːʍ nakištḭkatká̰n //
    \glb ka-tamáː-ʔḛː-w nak=kin-štḭkát-ka̰n //
    \glb \textsc{opt}-lie.down-\textsc{deb}-\textsc{1pl.sub} \textsc{loc}=1\textsc{po}-sleeping.mat-\textsc{pl.po} //
    \glft `Let’s lie down on our sleeping mats!' //
    \endgl
\a \begingl
    \gla a:'jtzananú: chiwíx xli:lh’a:'nankán //
    \glb a̰ːxtsananúː čiwíš ḭš-liː-ɬ’a̰ː-nan-kan //
    \glb long.ago rock \textsc{past}-\textsc{inst}-plow-\textsc{dtrns}-\textsc{idf} //
    \glft `Long ago they plowed with rocks.' //
    \endgl
\xe

\pex 2-3 Option: Top line is not aligned word-by-word
\a \begingl
    \glpreamble katamaːwḛ́ːʍ nakištḭkatká̰n //
    \gla ka-tamáː-ʔḛː-w nak=kin-štḭkát-ka̰n //
    \glb \textsc{opt}-lie.down-\textsc{deb}-\textsc{1pl.sub} \textsc{loc}=1\textsc{po}-sleeping.mat-\textsc{pl.po} //
    \glft `Let’s lie down on our sleeping mats!' //
    \endgl
\a \begingl
    \glpreamble a:'jtzananú: chiwíx xli:lh’a:'nankán //
    \gla a̰ːxtsananúː čiwíš ḭš-liː-ɬ’a̰ː-nan-kan //
    \glb long.ago rock \textsc{past}-\textsc{inst}-plow-\textsc{dtrns}-\textsc{idf} //
    \glft `Long ago they plowed with rocks.' //
    \endgl
\xe

\end{document}
```

[image]