# How to set up TeX software to begin making existing Greek and Hebrew texts into custom interlinear pdfs?

Tags: installing, compiling, greek, hebrew, tutorials

**Starting Point**

I have a W32TeX package with latex, pdftex, xetex installed on a win7 box and am interested in getting started creating interlinear Greek-Hebrew (2 line, no English) texts of Biblical passages (sourced from Hebrew OT, Septuagint, Greek NT, and Delitzsch's Hebrew NT translation in public domain).

I have bookmarked a good question on [doing an interlinear text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45520/doing-an-interlinear-text) and have perused and bookmarked some of the getting-started information. For example, [tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming) appears to cover some of the necessary faq pre-req.s for my question.

**What I need to know**

- What software package(s) is best suited for the purpose of arranging both Greek-to-Hebrew and Hebrew-to-Greek interlinear texts? (Hope this is not a purely subjective question). *An answer might be that XeTeX will work fine, or that "SomeOther"TeX is especially suited to RTL, LTR alterations within a line.*
- Additionally, what reading is essential to learn skills needed for preparing multi-line/language texts from existing written sources? *An answer would include some direction toward specific documentation available, or include a hyperlink to a multi-line tutorial that features working examples of methods specific to multi-line text.*
- Lastly, any tips on finding source texts from the public domain which may be easy for the beginner to set into multi-line texts? [To be honest, I am also trolling just for the source text files in [my question on the hermeneutics SE Site](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/4561/where-are-plain-text-files-of-greek-and-hebrew-biblical-source-texts-available)] **EDIT: the texts tips are in my comment below** *The source text basis may help to inform the rest of this question.*

**Purpose**
I use both Hebrew and Greek texts for regular reading, and do not like to read on the computer, or print poor copies. There are some good reading tools that just treat Hebrew or Greek with English, but I want to make publisher quality prints that pair 1) OT Hebrew with LXX, and 2) NT Greek with Delitzsch's Hebrew Translation. (If someone has a files set up for this and is willing to share that would be super awesome).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: **Here are Some Source Texts Available in Plain Text**
[Westminster Leningrad Codex Hebrew Text](http://www.tanach.us/Tanach.xml#Technical) see "Zipped Archives". [Rahlf's LXX](http://www.chinesetheology.com/Bible&Theology/LXXGreekOT.htm) see "zipped file of LXX text" (unzip, open & save as UTF-8, be patient, it's big). [SBL Greek New Testament](http://sblgnt.com/download/) see "Plaintext" link. [Delitzsch Hebrew New Testament](http://patrologia.narod.ru/biblia/hnt/delitzsh/index.htm) is a start.

Comment: A bounty of info at https://www.tug.org/interest.html#editors covers a wide variety of the field. For anyone interested in an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the `expex` package in the past for interlinear text (in my case, Portuguese and phonetic transcription; [here](http://cl.up.pt/arquivo/arquivo/alinhada/27.pdf)'s an example of what I achieved.)

Comment: Hi Thanks for posting an answer. Sorry I've been away for a while. Will check this out...

Comment: For reference, `expex` is at http://www.ctan.org/pkg/expex. The documentation looks like very easy to use for interlinear. Now on Ubuntu, would be using Tex Live, which comes with all the rest of the software needed. Looks like Miktex comes with expex, for Windows.