# How to do centered interlinear text in LaTeX

Tags: macros, linguistics

How to do interlinear text like below?

[image]

Especially, number over the word is centered in relation to this word. I tried with hbox and centering command but not works.

```
\def\wrd#1#2{$\vcenter{\hbox{\valign{&\hbox{\centering##}&\hbox{\strut##}\cr#1&#2\cr}}}$}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need `\vbox` and `\halign`, not `\valign`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\wrd[2]{%
  \leavevmode
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \halign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr
      {\footnotesize\sffamily\vphantom{p}#1}\cr
      \noalign{\vskip\lineskip}%
      \vphantom{A}#2\cr
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\linespread{1.8}\selectfont


\wrd{9176}{Longword} \wrd{12345}{a} \wrd{o12}{end}
\wrd{9176}{longword} \wrd{12345}{a} \wrd{o12}{end}
\wrd{9176}{longword} \wrd{12345}{a} \wrd{o12}{end}
\wrd{9176}{longword} \wrd{12345}{a} \wrd{o12}{end}
\wrd{9176}{longword} \wrd{12345}{a} \wrd{o12}{end}
\wrd{9176}{longword} \wrd{12345}{a} \wrd{o12}{end}
\wrd{9176}{longword} \wrd{12345}{a} \wrd{o12}{end}
\wrd{9176}{longword} \wrd{12345}{a} \wrd{o12}{end}
\wrd{9176}{longword} \wrd{12345}{a} \wrd{o12}{end}
\wrd{9176}{longword} \wrd{12345}{a} \wrd{o12}{end}
\wrd{9176}{longword} \wrd{12345}{a} \wrd{o12}{end}
\wrd{9176}{longword} \wrd{12345}{a} \wrd{o12}{end}
\wrd{9176}{longword} \wrd{12345}{a} \wrd{o12}{end}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is this part `\hfil##\hfil`? Is it causing the centering or is it the `\halign`?

Comment: @azetina It's the *template*: the `#` stands for the cell's content, which is so centered in the available width. We have to use `##` because it's inside a definition.

Comment: I understand the # and ## signs need but what is causing the centering? Is it the `\hfil`? So is `\hfil##\hfil` only being applied to the numbers?

Comment: @azetina No, it's applied to all the column (and there's only one).

Answer (score 11):

The [`expex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/expex) package is designed for creating interlinear linguistics examples, and it is easily adapted for texts of this type.

In order to center the number above the word (or group of words), use the `expex` option `glwordalign=center`.

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Palatino Linotype}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\newfontfamily\versefont{Tahoma}

\usepackage{expex}
\lingset{everygla=\footnotesize\sffamily, % formatting the numbers in the gla line
    glwordalign=center, % center alignment within glwords
    aboveglbskip=-0.4ex, % narrows the vertical gap between the gla and glb lines
    glhangstyle=none, % no hanging indent
    glspace=!0pt plus .2em, % widens the allowable space between glwords to avoid overfull lines
    glrightskip=0pt plus .5\hsize} % widens the allowable space between the right margin and the end of the last glword on a line to avoid overfull lines

\newcommand{\vs}[1]{{\bfseries\versefont #1}}

\begin{document}
\exdisplay
\begingl
\gla 976 {} 1078 2424 5547 5207 1138 5207 11 {} 11 1080 o2464 1161 2464 1080 o2384 1161 2384 1080 o2455 2532 o80 846 {} 1161 2455 1080 o5329 2532 o2196 1537 o2283 1161 5329 1080 o2074 1161 2074 1080 o689 {} 1161//
\glb \underline{Zwój księgi} (o) narodzinach Jezusa Chrystusa, syna Dawida, syna Abrahama. \vs{2} Abraham zrodził Izaaka, a Izaak zrodził Jakuba, a Jakub zrodził Judę, i braci jego, \vs{3} a Juda zrodził Faresa i Zarę z Tamary, a Fares zrodził Esroma, a Esrom zrodził Arama, \vs{4} a//
\endgl
\xe
\end{document}
```

[image]

My example above needs to be compiled with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, but this is just because of the way I selected fonts using `fontspec` and used Unicode input for the Polish. If you choose fonts and enter the Polish differently you can use pdfLaTeX.

See [Alan Munn's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45858/42880) to [Doing an interlinear text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45520/doing-an-interlinear-text) if you are interested in importing the numbers from an external concordance file.

I wasn't able to get the `lettrine` package (for the drop-cap chapter number) to play nicely with `expex` line breaking; you could ask about this in a separate question if it is important to you.

Comment: My solution to the `lettrine` issue is here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247339/42880.

Answer (score 7):

A layman's aapproach with  `tabular`

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\wrd[2]{%
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.4}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
   \footnotesize\textsf{#1}\\%
      #2
   \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\linespread{1.8}\selectfont


\wrd{9176}{Longword} \wrd{12345}{a} \wrd{o12}{end}
\wrd{9176}{longword} \wrd{12345}{a} \wrd{o12}{end}
\wrd{9176}{longword} \wrd{12345}{a} \wrd{o12}{end}
\wrd{9176}{longword} \wrd{12345}{a} \wrd{o12}{end}
\wrd{9176}{longword} \wrd{12345}{a} \wrd{o12}{end}
\wrd{9176}{longword} \wrd{12345}{a} \wrd{o12}{end}
\wrd{9176}{longword} \wrd{12345}{a} \wrd{o12}{end}
\wrd{9176}{longword} \wrd{12345}{a} \wrd{o12}{end}
\wrd{9176}{longword} \wrd{12345}{a} \wrd{o12}{end}
\wrd{9176}{longword} \wrd{12345}{a} \wrd{o12}{end}
\wrd{9176}{longword} \wrd{12345}{a} \wrd{o12}{end}
\wrd{9176}{longword} \wrd{12345}{a} \wrd{o12}{end}
\wrd{9176}{longword} \wrd{12345}{a} \wrd{o12}{end}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This shows that most functionality of TeX-core is available in the LaTeX2e layer. However, your `a`'s are "jumping" ...

Comment: @yo' Yes, good spotted. That is why the *teacher* added `\vphantom`s in his answer. ;)

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively using the `stackengine` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\wrd[2]{%
  \stackengine{0.2ex}{\vphantom{A}#1}{{\footnotesize\sffamily\vphantom{p}#2}}{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}%
}

\begin{document}

\wrd{hello}{12} world

\end{document}
```

See the `stackengine` manual, pg 6, for more information. Here is a snapshot of the interpretation of the above.

[image]

Comment: I would set `\useanchorwidth` to `F`, or else `\wrd{a}{1161}` will bump into adjacent text.

Comment: You could eliminate the `\vphantom`s if you chose a `L`ong stacktype and set the gap accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Using stacks.  Oops.  I see azetina beat me to it.  My MWE is a bit more elaborative, but give him the vote.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{palatino,setspace}
\newcommand\wrd[2]{\def\stacktype{L}\stackon[10pt]{#1}{\scriptsize\sffamily#2}}
\newcommand\verseno[1]{\bgroup\bfseries\sffamily#1\egroup}
\begin{document}
\doublespacing
\verseno{1} \wrd{\underline{Zwoj ksiegi}}{976} (o) \wrd{narodzinach}{1078} \wrd{Jesuza}{2424}
\wrd{Chrystusa}{5547}, \wrd{syna}{5207} \wrd{Dawida}{1138}, \wrd{syna}{5207}
\wrd{Abrahama}{11}. \verseno{2} \wrd{Abraham}{11} \wrd{zrodzil}{1080}
\wrd{Izaaka}{o2462}, \wrd{a}{1161} \wrd{Izaak}{2464} \wrd{zrodzil}{1080}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Lets just stick to your one. I mean you are the author :)

Answer (score 1):

One simple approach could be use an inline math environment using `\overset`, but may be you can be also interested in the source of the `dvgloss` package.  The format is not the required in this case (upper line is not  centered with sans serif}  but because he simpler sintaxis of `\gl` macro and some other feature worth take a look to source code of the package . Example:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dvgloss}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\def\verseno#1{{\bfseries\sffamily#1}}
\def\wrd#1#2{\ensuremath{\overset{\mathsf{#2}}{\textrm{\vphantom{I}#1}}}}
\begin{document}


Using \verb|\overset| from \verb|amsmath|:\\[1em]


\lettrine[lines=2,lraise=.4,findent=1em]{\verseno{1}}{} 
\wrd{\underline{Zwoj ksiegi}}{976} (o) \wrd{narodzinach}{1078} \wrd{Jesuza}{2424} \wrd{Chrystusa}{5547}, \wrd{syna}{5207} \wrd{Dawida}{1138}, \wrd{syna}{5207} \wrd{Abrahama}{11}. 
\verseno{\Large 2} \wrd{Abraham}{11} \wrd{zrodzil}{1080} \wrd{Izaaka}{o2462}, \wrd{a}{1161} \wrd{Izaak}{2464} \wrd{zrodzil}{1080}

\bigskip

With \verb|dvgloss|:\\[1em]

\lettrine[lines=2,lraise=0,findent=1em]{\verseno{1}}{} 
\gl{976  {~} 1078 * 2424 5547 * 5207 1138 5207 11 22 33 44}{{\underline{Zwoj ksiegi}} (o) narodzinach Jesuza Chrystusa, syna Dawida, syna Abrahama.}%
%
\verseno{\raisebox{-1.5ex}{\large 2}}  \gl{11 1080 o2462 1161 2464 1080}{Abraham zrodzil Izaaka, a Izaak zrodzil} 

\end{document}
```