# Doing an interlinear text - how to combine lettrine with expex?

Tags: lettrine, expex

I am doing interlinear text with expex as described in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224154/70881)

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Palatino Linotype}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\newfontfamily\versefont{Tahoma}

\usepackage{expex}
\lingset{everygla=\footnotesize\sffamily, % formatting the numbers in the gla line
    glwordalign=center, % center alignment within glwords
    aboveglbskip=-0.4ex, % narrows the vertical gap between the gla and glb lines
    glhangstyle=none, % no hanging indent
    glspace=!0pt plus .2em, % widens the allowable space between glwords to avoid overfull lines
    glrightskip=0pt plus .5\hsize} % widens the allowable space between the right margin and the end of the last glword on a line to avoid overfull lines

\newcommand{\vs}[1]{{\bfseries\versefont #1}}

\begin{document}
\exdisplay
\begingl
\gla 976 {} 1078 2424 5547 5207 1138 5207 11 {} 11 1080 o2464 1161 2464 1080 o2384 1161 2384 1080 o2455 2532 o80 846 {} 1161 2455 1080 o5329 2532 o2196 1537 o2283 1161 5329 1080 o2074 1161 2074 1080 o689 {} 1161//
\glb \underline{Zwój księgi} (o) narodzinach Jezusa Chrystusa, syna Dawida, syna Abrahama. \vs{2} Abraham zrodził Izaaka, a Izaak zrodził Jakuba, a Jakub zrodził Judę, i braci jego, \vs{3} a Juda zrodził Faresa i Zarę z Tamary, a Fares zrodził Esroma, a Esrom zrodził Arama, \vs{4} a//
\endgl
\xe
\end{document}
```

How to combine lettrine with expex to get text like bellow?

[image]

Comment: I guessed some packages (see edit) but still get  `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...b zrodził Judę, i braci jego, \vs` please complete the example to define `\vs` or anything else needed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `lettrine` options `loversize` to increase the height of the number and `lraise` to lower it into the right position relative to the text lines, as shown below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Palatino Linotype}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\newfontfamily\versefont{Tahoma}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{expex}
\lingset{everygla=\footnotesize\sffamily, % formatting the numbers in the gla line
    glwordalign=center, % center alignment within glwords
    aboveglbskip=-0.4ex, % narrows the vertical gap between the gla and glb lines
    glhangstyle=none, % no hanging indent
    glspace=!0pt plus .2em, % widens the allowable space between glwords to avoid overfull lines
    glrightskip=0pt plus .5\hsize} % widens the allowable space between the right margin and the end of the last glword on a line to avoid overfull lines

\newcommand{\vs}[1]{{\bfseries\versefont #1}}

\begin{document}
\exdisplay
\begingl
\lettrine[loversize=1,lraise=-1.3]{1 }{}%
\gla 976 {} 1078 2424 5547 5207 1138 5207 11 {} 11 1080 o2464 1161 2464 1080 o2384 1161 2384 1080 o2455 2532 o80 846 {} 1161 2455 1080 o5329 2532 o2196 1537 o2283 1161 5329 1080 o2074 1161 2074 1080 o689 {} 1161//
\glb \underline{Zwój księgi} (o) narodzinach Jezusa Chrystusa, syna Dawida, syna Abrahama. \vs{2} Abraham zrodził Izaaka, a Izaak zrodził Jakuba, a Jakub zrodził Judę, i braci jego, \vs{3} a Juda zrodził Faresa i Zarę z Tamary, a Fares zrodził Esroma, a Esrom zrodził Arama, \vs{4} a//
\endgl
\xe
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to make these settings apply to the whole document rather than just this one chapter number, you can use `\renewcommand{\DefaultLoversize}{1}` and `\renewcommand{\DefaultLraise}{-1.3}`.

Answer (score 3):

`lettrine` seems to need a bit of a push to play nicely, but....

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Palatino Linotype}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\newfontfamily\versefont{Tahoma}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{expex}
\lingset{everygla=\footnotesize\sffamily, % formatting the numbers in the gla line
    glwordalign=center, % center alignment within glwords
    aboveglbskip=-0.4ex, % narrows the vertical gap between the gla and glb lines
    glhangstyle=none, % no hanging indent
    glspace=!0pt plus .2em, % widens the allowable space between glwords to avoid overfull lines
    glrightskip=0pt plus .5\hsize} % widens the allowable space between the right margin and the end of the last glword on a line to avoid overfull lines

\newcommand{\vs}[1]{{\bfseries\versefont #1}}

\begin{document}
\exdisplay
\begingl
\lettrine[lines=1,loversize=.3]{\raisebox{-15pt}{\bfseries1 }}{}%
\gla 976 {} 1078 2424 5547 5207 1138 5207 11 {} 11 1080 o2464 1161 2464 1080 o2384 1161 2384 1080 o2455 2532 o80 846 {} 1161 2455 1080 o5329 2532 o2196 1537 o2283 1161 5329 1080 o2074 1161 2074 1080 o689 {} 1161//
\glb \underline{Zwój księgi} (o) narodzinach Jezusa Chrystusa, syna Dawida, syna Abrahama. \vs{2} Abraham zrodził Izaaka, a Izaak zrodził Jakuba, a Jakub zrodził Judę, i braci jego, \vs{3} a Juda zrodził Faresa i Zarę z Tamary, a Fares zrodził Esroma, a Esrom zrodził Arama, \vs{4} a//
\endgl
\xe
\end{document}
```