# Modifying A Specific Example of Interlinear Text and Running it on Tex Live 2018

Tags: errors, xetex, datatool, expex

I am trying to modify this specific solution to interlinear texts, which I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45520/doing-an-interlinear-text#45858).

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainlanguage{brazil}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{expex}

% Format chapter and verse (\section) headings
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\filcenter}
 {\LARGE\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
 {1pc}
 {\vspace{1pc}%
   \LARGE}
\titlespacing{\chapter}
{0pt}{0pt}{10pt}

\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]
 {\normalfont
  \vspace{0pt}%
   \bfseries\Large\filleft}
{\thesection}{.5em}{} 
\titlespacing{\section}
{4pc}{1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{0pt}

% format section label
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}:\arabic{section}}

% multiple gloss lines will align on the left margin
\lingset{glhangstyle=none}

% initialize some token registers to build up the lines from the database cells
\newtoks\glosslineA
\newtoks\glosslineB
\newtoks\glosslineC

% create a command to append a cell to the token register
% Thanks to Enrico Gregorio for this code
\long\def\Append#1#2{#1=\expandafter{%
  \the\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter#1\expandafter\space #2}}

% Define a command to empty the token registers
\def\emptytoks{\glosslineA{}\glosslineB{}\glosslineC{}}

% Define a command used to escape * in the input cell
\def\esc#1{#1} % 
\def\SecTest{section} % verse delimiter check

\begin{document}
\DTLsetseparator{   }% literal tab; with UTF8 source, \DTLsettabseparator doesn't work
\DTLloaddb{text}{Chapter2.csv}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\chapter{O sonhou do Nabucodonsor}
\DTLforeach{text}
{% assign each cell in a row to a macro
    \Codes=Number,
    \GreekText=Greek,
    \PortugueseText=Portuguese%
}
{% If we're in the first row, start a section; otherwise if we find a section, output
%  the previous section's lines, and start a new section, then empty the token registers
    \DTLiffirstrow{\section{}}{
    \DTLifeq{\Codes}{\SecTest}{
    \begingl
        \expandafter\gla\the\glosslineA//
        \expandafter\glb\the\glosslineB//
        \expandafter\glc\the\glosslineC//
    \endgl
    \section{}
    \emptytoks
    }
    {% For each cell, append it to the token register for that line
    \Append\glosslineA{\Codes}%
    \Append\glosslineB{\GreekText}%
    \Append\glosslineC{\PortugueseText}%
}}}
% output the last section's lines.
\begingl
    \expandafter\gla\the\glosslineA//
    \expandafter\glb\the\glosslineB//
    \expandafter\glc\the\glosslineC//
\endgl

\end{document}
```

First, I need to make it work on Windows with Tex Live 2018, which I installed from the DVD.  When I try to run it in Texmaker, an error message appears.

```
\dtlcols@text=\count308
! Argument of \@dtl@lopoff has an extra }.
```

But I know that this is a red herring, because the exact same code works perfectly with Tex Live 2017 under Linux.  I think that the problem is that the CSV is not being read for some reason.  (I'm using the same CSV that was posted in that thread.)  Has there been a change in the behavior of one of the packages from 2017 to 2018?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Your example compiles fine for me with an up-to-date texlive2018. Can you try to update to the current version?

Comment: Please don't ask multiple question in the same question. Maybe it would be better to move your questions about grids and stuff to a separate question.

Comment: @samcarter Strange. This fails for me with TL2018 with the same error.  And there was a change `datatool` using that macro between TL2017 and TL2018.

Comment: @AlanMunn Which operating system do you have?

Comment: @samcarter I'm using a Mac. (Same as you, I think?)

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes, that is very strange!

Comment: @AlanMunn I was too lazy to create .csv file myself, so I used `filecontents` to create it. Maybe some problem with encoding of the .csv file? (This works for me: https://gist.github.com/samcarter/04f867916fc62d6f11673d4155cd638c with TL18, updated this morning)

Comment: @samcarter Are you sure you get no errors? If I push through the errors I get output.

Comment: @AlanMunn I just checked my log file again, no errors (https://gist.github.com/samcarter/f6a6bcb0a60a72242564489a57fc8dae)

Comment: @samcarter Wierd, I just made a copy of the `.csv` file from the original answer and the file now compiles without error. But my original test files don't work with TL 2018 although they do with TL 2017.

Comment: @AlanMunn Maybe this are strange Halloween effects everything works fine tomorrow?

Comment: No error for me.

Comment: As far as I am aware, I have the latest version. I installed Tex Live 2018 from the DVD yesterday.  And as I mentioned, the same code works for me in Tex Live 2017 so it's not an issue with the code itself (or the CSV).

Comment: @MilesO'Brien Can you check if https://gist.github.com/samcarter/04f867916fc62d6f11673d4155cd638c works for you (preferably in a new folder)?

Comment: `\DTLsettabseparator` works fine for me. Your use of `\DTLsetseparator` with a literal tab as the argument will set the separator to a space because that's how (La)TeX usually interprets the TAB character. You'd need to change the catcode of TAB first in order to use TAB in `\DTLsetseparator` (as in @AlanMunn's deleted answer). It also might be worth checking both the `.tex` and `.csv` files in an editor that has an option to show visible spaces to make sure that any copying&pasting or downloading hasn't performed a silent conversion of TAB.

Comment: @samcarter That works.  I see that it generates a CSV.  Is there a way to read from an existing CSV?

Comment: @Nicola Talbot Thank you for the information about the "tab" character, but the CSV I am using works in Tex Live 2017, so I don't think that there's been any silent conversion.

Comment: @MilesO'Brien From the discussion with AlanMunn I suspect that the problem is the encoding of the file. If the existing cvs file has the correct encoding it should also work.

Comment: In that case, I simply don't understand it.  The CSV was created with Libre Office and saved at UTF-8 with TAB as the delimiter, just at the original example.  Does Windows handle this differently from Linux?

Comment: @Nicola Talbot Changing \DTLsetseparator to \DTLsettabseparator works for me in TL 2018 and proves that there is nothing wrong with the format of my spreadsheet.  Apologies!  For some reason, I was so focused on the second half of your post that I didn't think to try the first.  I am grateful to everyone who helped.

Comment: @AlanMunn Your answer that you deleted does actually seem to be the correct answer.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I've undeleted my answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following changes to the document.

Comment out the following line:

```
\DTLsetseparator{   }% literal tab; with UTF8 source, \DTLsettabseparator% doesn't work
```

And replace it with:

```
\DTLsettabseparator % add this line
```

Then after you load the CSV file, add the following line:

```
\DTLmaketabspace % immediately after loading  add this line
```

So the complete loading lines should now read:

```
\DTLsettabseparator % add this line
\DTLloaddb{text}{Chapter2.csv} % load file
\DTLmaketabspace % immediately after loading  add this line
```